# Turn off a screenshot on the phone by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I prevent a screenshot from the phone on my site by javascript or jquery

Comment: You cannot. A screenshot doesn't need to use the browser and usually doesn't - it tends to be an OS feature. You cannot block OS functionality.

Comment: That's like asking you how to prevent the phone from being switched off via javascript.

Comment: But how this is done via Facebook from the phone : Browser

Comment: Just took a screenshot of chrome with facebook open - no worries.  Are you sure you've opened facebook in a browser (which browser?) and not the facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's done at the OS level, your code doesn't get a chance to decide whether the user can take a picture of what they're seeing.

Comment: ...nor *should* it get that chance. :-)

Comment: But how this is done via Facebook from the phone : Browser

Comment: @SpyShare - It isn't, reliably. I just took a screenshot in Facebook on my iPhone.